# How to make Python SHA-256 digest match Java SHA-256 digest?

Tags: java, python, hash, hashlib

I have a Java application that generates tokens using SHA-256 hashes. I am trying to port the implementation to Python 3 as part of an end-to-end testing suite.

I've tried following the same steps in the Python implementation as are taken in the Java implementation, yet I'm getting different hex encoded results. Java is using JDK 11 and I am using Python 3.7.

Here is the Java implementation:

```java
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
...

text = "{\"1\":\"" + num + "\"}";
MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
mDigest.update(text.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET));
mDigest.update(data1.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET));
mDigest.update(data2.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET));
hash = Hex.encodeHexString(mDigest.digest());
```

Here is the Python implementation:

```py
from hashlib import sha256
...

text = "{\"1\": \"" + str(num) + "\"}"
mDigest = sha256()
mDigest.update(text.encode("UTF-8"))
mDigest.update(data1.encode("UTF-8"))
mDigest.update(data2.encode("UTF-8"))
hash = mDigest.hexdigest()
```

num, data1, and data2 are presumably the same for both implementations. The sample outputs that I've received from the Java application differ from my Python output despite having the same inputs. From peering over other StackOverflow posts I'm wondering if it could have to do with padding in the update or digest functions.

Comment: You have a space in python string `text = "{\"1\": \"" + str(num) + "\"}"` after the `:`. So your text inputs are not the same.

Comment: wow... that solved it. Thanks!
Edit: I'm surprised because prior to this string concatenation I was doing json.dumps on dictionaries as well as just doing str({"1": str(num)}) and neither were working.